# [Linux]restrict cpu usage by group or user

Tags: linux, cpu

I need restrict cpu usage by group or user
have any software can do this
1.I have study  cpulimit,but cpulimit can not by group or user,cpulimit only can by process or process id
2.I have study /etc/security/limits.conf,but only restrict cpu time,not cpu usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this you can use linux cgroup, for more information you read can the linux kernel Docs Documentation/cgroups/cgroups.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ulimit -a` for checking which limits were allocated to particular user for cpu limit you can try

```
ulimit -t
```

You can set cpu limit by

```
ulimit -t 100
```

There is man pages for getrlimit() and setrlimit() which are used by ulimit

```
   RLIMIT_CPU
          CPU time limit in seconds.  When the process reaches the soft limit, it is sent a SIGXCPU signal.  The default action for this  sig‐
          nal is to terminate the process.  However, the signal can be caught, and the handler can return control to the main program.  If the
          process continues to consume CPU time, it will be sent SIGXCPU once per second until the hard limit is reached, at which time it  is
          sent SIGKILL.  (This latter point describes Linux behavior.  Implementations vary in how they treat processes which continue to con‐
          sume CPU time after reaching the soft limit.  Portable applications that need to catch this signal should perform an orderly  termi‐
          nation upon first receipt of SIGXCPU.)
```

NOTE: cpu time value is in seconds.

Comment: but only restrict cpu time,not cpu usage